# Edit string input for geometry nodes?

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

How can I edit a string input in geometry nodes from the modifier properties? It seems to be the only type that cannot be edited (other than "Geometry" which just doesn't display at all).

Comment: I have had no trouble with this. Are you sure the type of input is set right?

Comment: Yes, it's set to "String". I have another input for a camera set to "Object" and it works just fine.

Comment: What version of Blender are you using?

Comment: 3.5.1. I noticed the issue on 3.5.0, but updating changed nothing in a fresh project.

Answer (score 0):

No problem editing string from modifier:

[image]

Make sure you have "Hide in Modifier" unchecked:

[image]

**Edit:**
Blender 3.5.1

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary as far as I can tell:
https://imgur.com/a/Bg29y9O
Also, "Hide in Modifier" doesn't seem to work either:

Comment: @Sandberg Strange... it does look correct in your screenshot. Could you maybe upload the file in your question? Or probably is something messed up with the node, does it work if you delete it and create a new one?

Comment: It seems like you're using a custom display of the modifier stack, either through modifying the source code or an add-on. Try disabling it or using an official version

Comment: @Gorgious Heaven's sake, that was it. And it looks like the issue was fixed in the latest version of the add-on.